# Tyvokka and Wookiee Jedi. Are they possible, and why or why not?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

I'm really interested to hear positive opinions that could support and or refute the possibility of Wookiee's becoming a Jedi.  I understand it may be an uphill battle, but [there is a precedent](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tyvokka).  Please help me understand you opinions and ideas.

I run a Star-Wars saga edition RPG game and have one Wookiee Jedi in my campaign and am interested in people's pros and cons.  Ideas and feedback, and hope to hear from as many people as possible on both sides of the coin, from a positive standpoint though, no scoffers or negative people please...

Comment: After editing your question, I realize I misunderstood it. As written, your question (looking for opinions) is a bad fit or our format. You can ask if any exist (but it seems you already know they do) or why they don't, but asking us to weigh the pros and cons isn't really what the Stack Exchange network is for

Comment: This would be a good topic to discuss in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley), but the main site is not intended to serve as a forum for discussion or opinion.  The main site is for questions like "Has there ever been a Wookiee Jedi?", not "What would the pros and cons of a Wookiee Jedi be?".

Comment: A better way to ask this for Stack Exchange might be "Why are Wookies rare candidates for the Jedi order?" Maybe it's obvious to everyone else why there aren't more wookie Jedi but I'd be interested to hear the reasons such a prominent race is so under represented. Are they immune to the force or something?

Answer (score 5):

This has happened at least once in Canon. Meet Gungi:

[image]

Gungi is a Jedi youngling who appears in a few episodes of *The Clone Wars* animated show.

The lightsaber-contruction training droid Huayang mentions that Wookiees are rare as Jedi:

> **Huyang:** A Wookiee! Rare you are to the Jedi. Proud, your people must be.
>
> <sup>*The Clone Wars* Season 5 Episode 7: "A Test of Strength"</sup>

But they are evidently possible.

There were a few more in Legends:

- Tyvokka, pointed out in the question
- Lowbacca, nephew of Chewbacca and close friend of Jaina and Jacen Solo

Answer (score 2):

After [Lowbacca](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lowbacca) (Chewbacca's nephew) was made into a Jedi in [*The Dark Nest* trilogy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dark_Nest_Trilogy), **George Lucas explicitly said that there would be no more Wookiee Jedi after him.*** And as he ran the company before its purchase to Disney, that was the end of that debate.

Notably, this affected [Hannhar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hanharr) in *[Knights of the Old Republic II: The Sith Lords](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars%3A_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II%3A_The_Sith_Lords)*. They made a big deal about how The Exile unconsciously drew force-sensitive people to her, yet Hanharr is one of only two non-droid party members who isn't able to be turned into a Jedi.

It seems that by the time *The Clone Wars* TV series came around, Lucas changed his mind by allowing [Gungi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gungi) to be a Jedi. Then again, the episode he first appeared in was aired three days after he announced the sale of Lucasfilm to Disney, so perhaps he relented on his no-Wookiee Jedi policy knowing that the company would no longer be his.

For the sake of completeness: the other Wookiee Jedi are [Tyvokka](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tyvokka) and [Kirlocca](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kirlocca).

<sub>* This was stated in the [Star Wars Insider 79](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_79) web supplement called "Wookiees: No Trivia Too Small". Unfortunately, this was behind a paywall in the now defunct [Star Wars Hyperspace](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperspace:_The_Official_Star_Wars_Fan_Club), and it has never been republished.</sub>

Comment: Did anyone mention *why* the rule of no Wookie Jedi?  Was there some difficulty, was there some other reason given?  It seems kind of random, if not...

Comment: @Megha The article unfortunately didn't mention why George Lucas made that rule. If I were to guess, it was because he preferred that Wookiees be defined by their strength and temper, and since Jedi don't need those, a Wookiee Jedi would be less "Wookiee-like". Kind of like how Tolkien had Dwarves be "miners" and Elves be "woodsmen", and didn't mix those up with cave-loving Elves or woods-loving Dwarves. It's simpler for the audience to more easily classify species that way, and is similar to how Flash Gordon treated aliens, which was a big inspiration for Star Wars.

Comment: But there was exceptions as forest dwarves http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Petty-dwarves ; cave elf http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/E%C3%B6l

Comment: @nicolallias I’m less familiar with Tolkien than with Star Wars. Regardless, I’m just speculating with Lucas’ rationale.

Comment: And your answer and commentary are absolutely valid, I was just quibbling :)